# WooCommerce: How can I get orders with a custom ID in order meta data object?

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic

Because of a project I need help from you. I've searched a lot but I can't find a solution.
I'm trying to edit a WooCommerce function named

- > woocommerce_account_orders

---

I've added the field

- > mycustom_id

to the the orders meta-data object because I need to get all orders which has the current logged in user in the field mycustom_id:

- > (mycustom_id = current_user_id())

---

The check for the `customer` should stay. I just need to add this other `current_user_id` check.

This sould stay as it is:

- > 'customer' => get_current_user_id()

---

. This is my not working code snippet:

```
function woocommerce_account_orders( $current_page ) {
    $current_page    = empty( $current_page ) ? 1 : absint( $current_page );
    $customer_orders = wc_get_orders( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', array(
        'customer' => get_current_user_id(),
        'mycustom_id' => get_current_user_id(),
        'page'     => $current_page,
        'paginate' => true,
    ) ) );

    wc_get_template(
        'myaccount/orders.php',
        array(
            'current_page'    => absint( $current_page ),
            'customer_orders' => $customer_orders,
            'has_orders'      => 0 < $customer_orders->total,
        )
    );
}
```

The method is located in: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-woocommerce_account_orders.html#2465-2486

---

How can I add this feature to the function a smart way like a filter and how can I pass my custom parameter the right way to the function? I've saved the parameter as an order_meta attribute:

```
[5] => WC_Meta_Data Object (
     [current_data:protected] => Array (
          [id] => 3477
          [key] => mycustom_id
          [value] => 2
)
```

Thank you for your help. I've tried so much but I'm new in PHP and must lurn a lot..

Answer (score 1):

I know this is very old but I would just like to share the solution.

Apparently, WooCommerce is ignoring the meta_query parameter. What you should do is something like:

```
function woocommerce_account_orders( $current_page ) {
    $current_page    = empty( $current_page ) ? 1 : absint( $current_page );
    $customer_orders = wc_get_orders( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', array(
        'customer' => get_current_user_id(),
        'mycustom_id' => get_current_user_id(),
        'page'     => $current_page,
        'paginate' => true,
        'meta_key'     => 'mycustom_id',
        'meta_compare' => '=',
        'meta_value'   => get_current_user_id(),
    ) ) );

    wc_get_template(
        'myaccount/orders.php',
        array(
            'current_page'    => absint( $current_page ),
            'customer_orders' => $customer_orders,
            'has_orders'      => 0 < $customer_orders->total,
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would add the `meta_query` portion to your `wc_get_orders()` as the only filter ...

```
function woocommerce_account_orders( $current_page ) {
    $current_page    = empty( $current_page ) ? 1 : absint( $current_page );
    $customer_orders = wc_get_orders( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', array(
        'page'     => $current_page,
        'paginate' => true,

        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'mycustom_id',
                'value' => get_current_user_id(),
                'compare' => '='
            )
        )

    ) ) );

    wc_get_template(
        'myaccount/orders.php',
        array(
            'current_page'    => absint( $current_page ),
            'customer_orders' => $customer_orders,
            'has_orders'      => 0 < $customer_orders->total,
        )
    );
}
```

This basically says get all the orders where order `meta_key = 'mycustom_id'` and `meta_value = $current_user_id`.